# Does HTTP Keep Alive reduce TLS connections?

Tags: http, ssl

I have read multiple threads like [thread1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56623/avoiding-ssl-handshake-for-each-call), [thread2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work/20847#20847) or [thread3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848099/multiple-ssl-tls-handshakes-despite-keep-alive-and-session-identifier-ticket-ena) on how tls handshakes are handled and how Keep Alive works.

To me it remains a bit unclear if I can avoid handshakes by using HTTP keep alive.

I have read about full TLS handshakes and abbreviated TLS handshakes. I understand tha you can bypass handshake steps by keeping TLS sessions. I would like to clarify if I can send multiple HTTP1.1 requests by using Keep Alive settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP keep alive is not about full and abbreviated TLS handshakes. HTTP keep alive is about **reusing the same connection for multiple HTTP requests and responses**. This implicitly also reduces the number of TLS handshakes since there is only one TLS handshake done per TCP connection, i.e. in case of HTTP keep alive **one TCP and one TLS handshake for multiple HTTP requests**.